# date and hours from datetime [python]

Tags: python, datetime

I have `datetime` parameter in pandas dataframe, with time that include minutes and seconds .

```
 index                 date
0         2021-03-01 07:55:00
1         2021-03-01 07:56:13
2         2021-03-01 07:56:43
3         2021-03-01 07:57:19
4         2021-03-01 07:57:57
       
5         2021-03-01 11:39:25
6         2021-03-01 11:39:59
7         2021-03-01 11:40:53
8         2021-03-01 11:41:44
9         2021-03-01 11:43:31
```

how can I create parameter like this  (date and hour)

```
    index                   date
    0         2021-03-01 07:00:00
    1         2021-03-01 07:00:00
    2         2021-03-01 07:00:00
    3         2021-03-01 07:00:00 
    4         2021-03-01 07:00:00
           
    5         2021-03-01 11:00:00
    6         2021-03-01 11:00:00
    7         2021-03-01 11:00:00
    8         2021-03-01 11:00:00
    9         2021-03-01 11:00:00
```

Comment: are you using `pandas`? your sample looks like a pd.Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

The data is in fact a pandas DataFrame with the column containing `datetime` objects. Given that the column is named "date" here's one way to effect the change:

```
df = df['date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(minute=0, second=0))
print(df)
```

```
0   2021-03-01 07:00:00
1   2021-03-01 07:00:00
2   2021-03-01 07:00:00
3   2021-03-01 07:00:00
4   2021-03-01 07:00:00
5   2021-03-01 11:00:00
6   2021-03-01 11:00:00
7   2021-03-01 11:00:00
8   2021-03-01 11:00:00
9   2021-03-01 11:00:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Original answer follows...

---

Use [`datetime.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to reset the minute and second in the datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime('2021-03-01 07:55:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dt = dt.replace(minute=0, second=0)
print(dt)
# 2021-03-01 07:00:00
```

Your examples do not appear to have resolution smaller than one second, however, if it does, you could also set microseconds to 0 too:

```
dt = dt.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Comment: thank you :)    when I put the parameter in   dt = datetime.strptime(df['datetime'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') . it says  module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'    .        its a parameter from dataframe and not just a list.     edit.   I import and it says   :  " strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series" .   again..its a parameter from dataframe

Comment: Please check that your import is `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: @rafine: please update your question to make it clear that your data is a pandas dataframe and not a list, It obviously makes a difference.

Comment: @rafine: no worries.